# Difference between $a^{2n} b^n$ and $n_a(w) = 2n_b(w)$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I have encountered two questions related to npda:

1. Construct an npda for $L_1 = \{a^{2n} b^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ as a language over $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$.
2. Construct an npda for $L_2 = \{w \in \{a, b, c\}^* \mid n_a(w) = 2n_b(w)\}$.

What is the difference between the above two languages?

Comment: Could you add a bit more context to these questions? What are "a_concatenation_n" or "na(w)", for example?

Comment: The second is a strict superset of the first. Examples of words included only in the second language are $c,aba,baa$.

Comment: First one can have strings like: aab, aaaabb, what about the possibility of 'c' in the first one? Please guide me.@siracusa: Sorry its same as a^2n b ^n. Some people says that use of power symbol not good in place of concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition is that $n_a(w)$ refers to the number of $a$s in $w$.

Based on this definition, $L_1$ consists exactly of words that begin with an even number of $a$s followed by half as many $b$s (no $c$s are permitted). Therefore, you have $\varepsilon, aab, aaaabb, aaaaaabbb,... \in L_1$.

Whereas $L_2$ consists of words containing an even number of $a$s and half as many $b$s (in *any order* and with an arbitrary number of $c$ in between).

Thus every word in $L_1$ is also in $L_2$ (formally $L_1 \subseteq L_2$), but there are words in $L_2$ that are not in $L_1$:

- For some $n \geq 0$, consider words of the form $b^n a^{2n}$. They are in $L_2$, because they contain an even number of $a$s and half as many $b$s, but if $n > 0$, then it does not match $a^{2n} b^n$, because the $a$s come after the $b$s. You have $\varepsilon, baa,bbaaa,bbbaaaaaa,... \in L_2$, but $baa,bbaaa,bbbaaaaaa \notin L_1$.
- The same argument applies for $w = (aab)^n$. You have $\varepsilon, aab,aabaab,aabaabaab \in L_2$, but $aabaab,aabaabaab \notin L_1$.
- A word can have an even number of $a$s and half as many $b$s and also contain $c$s. For example, $a^{2n} b^n c \in L_2$. But the words in $L_1$ by definition only contain $a$s and $b$s.

Answer (score 1):

In both languages, each string must have twice as many $a$'s as $b$'s.  For a string to be in the first language, it must satisfy the additional condition that all the $a$'s occur before any of the $b$'s.  So $aba$ does not belong to the first language and does belong to the second language.